# Paste multiple lines with sun vi

Tags: solaris, vi

All machines in my university are all solaris, various updates and various hardware.
Mission was to copy and paste a line in vi say 500 times. I tried the 
usual yy, to copy the line I wanted, then 500p

It only pasted one line. Tried a bunch of other machines, no dice.

Had another person try the same task, they failed as well and were like 
WTF is going on here.

Talked to the programmers, they only use vim, where this does work. 
Is there a reason this pretty basic behavior doens't work on the sun 
standard vi, or is there something that would make it not work?

Comment: vim isn't vi (incidentally, vim supposedly is closer to Solaris vi than to AIX for instance).

Comment: But on Solaris 11.0 and later, vi is vim.  (At least `/usr/bin/vi` is - the older vi is still in `/usr/xpg4/bin` and `/usr/sun/bin` on Solaris 11.)

Comment: Does `yy5p` work? Does `5rx` work? Is your problem the 500 times?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. it only paste one line

Comment: `yyp99.` doesn't work either (copies the line only twice).

Comment: fwiw, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#tag_20_152_13_69) agrees with vim in this case.